# Automount vfat (w95 fat32 LBA) on Centos

Tags: linux, centos, mount, automount

I'm trying to mount an USB flash drive formatted as w95 fat32 LBA (as reported by dmesg) under Centos. I can easily mount it using the mount command:

```
mount /dev/sdx1 /media/mydrive -t vfat
```

But it seems that the system (Centos 6.3) cannot mount it automatically. It mounts all the other filesystem types automatically. I also installed fuse-ntfs and it correctly mounts NTFS drives.
How can I enable automount for vfat partiotions too?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to the end of /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/sdx1 /media/mydrive vfat default 0 0
```

and reboot:

```
sudo reboot -n
```

`defaults` means use default settings, equivalent to rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,nouser,async. Read more with `man fstab`.

Comment: Don't you mean `defaults`?

Comment: This will mount the drive at boot, but I think the OP wanted it to automount when he inserts it.

Answer (score 0):

add this to /etc/fstab:

```
/media/mydrive    /dev/sdx1    vfat    defaults    0 0
```

check that all works by command

```
mount -a
```

Comment: I would like to activate the automount as for other USB pen drives, so when i plugin another usb the folder is created automatically and the drive mounted.

Comment: check autofs, it's may help - http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-nfs-config-autofs.html

Comment: You've reversed the first two parameters.